# Start Android activity from list of activities

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, start-activity

I am working on one android app, and in which i have one menu that shows list of Activity name.Upon clicking of any item from menu should start that specific Activity.

One way i know to do this is,

```
String classes[]= {"firstActivity","DetailActivity"}; intent i =new Intent(pkg_name+classes[position]);startActivity(i);
```

where position=0 or 1.
And for that i need to write in AndroidManifest.xml file below code for each Activity

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.day1.DetailActivity"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.day1.DetailActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But i want just

```
<activity android:name=".DetailActivity"></activity>
```

simple code. Dont want to use intent-filter So please give me alternative i can use in this case.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or the other way round

```
Class classes[] = [ firstActivity.class, DetailActivity.class];
Intent i = new Intent(this, classes[position]);
startActivity(i);
```

Then, when you want to display the name of the activities, use `classes[position].getSimpleName();`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
Class chooseClass = null;
switch(position)
{
case 0 : chooseClass = firstActivity;
         break;
case 1 : chooseClass = DetailActivity;
         break;
}
if(chooseClass != null)
    startActivity(new Intent(context, chooseClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Via code you can launch it with:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Now you don't need the filter.